# lua - return value if string match with wildcard

Tags: lua

I have never worked with lua before and am having a hard time trying to figure out how to return a value based on a string match with wildcard...thank you in advance for any help.

here is the script ive been tasked with modifying.   The last bit where I'm looking for Bob* is where I'm stuck.

```
if score < 3000 then
return 180
end
if score > 2999 and score < 10000 then
return 90
end
if score > 9999 and score < 25000 then
return 30
end
if score > 24999 then
return 7
end

if name = string.match(name, 'Bob*')
return 0
end
;
```

Comment: Standard wildcards `?` and `*` look like this in Lua: `.` and `.*`  Correct syntax is `if string.match(name, '^Bob.*$') then return 0 end`

Answer (score 1):

Wildcards (`?`, `*`) in lua are `.` and `.*`. 
Correct if condition:

```
if name = string.match(name, '^Bob.*$') then
return 0
end
```

PS. What's up with semicolon and end of code?